# How to replace Flowable with another without resubscribing

Tags: java, rx-java2

I've got interface with function which returns Flowable

```
interface Iface{
   Flowable<Int> get();
}
```

Let's for now assume, that the concrete implementation is:

```
class IFaceImpl{
  int noOfSecs = 1;
  Flowable<Int> get(){
    return Flowable.interval(noOfSecs,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to change the `noOfSecs` parameter in the way, that the Flowable.interval will produce events every 2s, instead of one. It would be easy, when the client could just resubscribe. In my case, I cannot do this, and I would like client to subscribe only once, but be able to change emitting frequency of Flowable to change.

What is the best way of doing stuff like that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `switchMap` to dynamically stop a previous interval and start a new interval.

```java
class IfaceImpl {
    final Subject<Long> nextInterval = 
        BehaviorSubject.createDefault(1)
        .toSerialized();

    Flowable<Long> get() {
        return nextInterval.switchMap(seconds -> 
            Flowable.interval(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        );
    }

    void setNumberOfSeconds(int seconds) {
        nextInterval.onNext(seconds);
    }
}
```